# Tooltip on hovering and showing the result of func

Tags: html, angular, tooltip

I have "RowsLenght" and i need to see the tooltip when I hover on it but showing the result of {{row.boxes.length}} in addtion to "No." txt.
I mean forexample I want to see "5 No." in the tooltip. Would you please help?

```
<div> {{'RowsLenght' | translate}}
          <span > ({{row.boxes.length}} )</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-vwnwno?file=src/app/app.component.scss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to simply use the html title attribute on your div:

```
<div title="No. {{ row.boxes.length }}">
  {{'RowsLenght' | translate}}
</div>
```